# What should be a simple implicit derivative

Tags: implicit-differentiation

I'm currently working my way through an economics paper which has a derivative that at the moment I'm failing to see. I was hoping that it would be a simple case of the implicit function theorem however, using that approach I don't find the correct answer. If someone could suggest what I'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated. I apologise if this seems trivial.

We are given the equation 
\begin{equation}
c^*=\frac{b(e)y+a\int_{0}^{c^*} cdG(c)}{r+b(e)+aG(c^*)}
\end{equation}
where $G$ is a distribution function. The goal is to compute the derivative 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dc^*}{de}=\frac{(y-c^*)b'(e)}{r+b+aG}
\end{equation}
To my mind I would use the implicit function theorem to compute 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dc^*}{de}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial e}\bigg/\frac{\partial H}{\partial c^*}
\end{equation}
where $H$ is given by 
\begin{equation}
H=c^*-\frac{b(e)y+a\int_{0}^{c^*} cdG(c)}{r+b(e)+aG(c^*)}=0
\end{equation}
Also using the Leibniz integral rule 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial c^*}\int_{0}^{c^*} cdG(c)=G(c^*)
\end{equation}
Does this look like the correct strategy?

Comment: In your original equation, does $y$ depend on $e$? Does $a$? $c$? $G$? $r$? Is there a relationship between $c$ and $c^{*}$?